# Edit confluence page via python script

Tags: python, confluence

I need to access a Confluence page via python script and change all 'use_windows' strings to 'use_linux' strings

```
from sh import sed
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
url='https://confluence.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=89967548'
username='user'
password='passs')
```

I can use want use this command inside of script:

```
sed(['-i', 's/use_windows/use_linux/'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you use the https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api lib. You do NOT need to specify direct URL to page, just Confluence SERVER URL (to core page): "https://confluence.com".

Here is the option:

```
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://my-confluence-site.com',
    username='admin',
    password='admin')
    page_id = 111111 # page id (or you can use space and title)
    page_body = get_page_by_id(page_id ).get("body").get("storage").get("value")
    page_body = page_body.replace("use_windows", "use_linux")    

   # set the new body for page
   update_existing_page(page_id, title, page_body)
```

Comment: Do we have a way to download the page as html or pdf